# CSS 4-way rocker control

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to do some 2-axis adjustment on a web page.

Can anyone point me at the CSS/Javascript for a 4-way rocker switch like the ones on TV remotes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find anything in my searches of the web, and nobody here had a suggestion, so I wrote one.

Live demo: [Resizable 4-Way Rocker Control Widget](http://netfools.com/rocker/)

See the code: [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RAMilewski/njUe6/)